# Compile sequence of arithmetic operations on the fly

Tags: c, math, compiler-construction

I wrote a program in C to generate fractals using a formula, but it goes very slow. Basically you pass the rendering function a bunch of unsigned char numbers that indicate functions to push values on to a stack or pop them off and perform and arithmetic operation and push the result back on the stack (kind of like reverse polish notation). The problem is, the program is reading these functions numbers, going through an if...else if...else if...else if...elseif... to find the right operation to perform, and pushing and popping a bunch of values for every iteration in every pixel. Normally there would just be a formula (like the Mandelbrot) hard coded into the rendering function, but this program is a DLL I'm writing to be an all purpose fractal renderer. Is there any way I could write a little mini compiler that reads the formula before rendering begins and compiles a function on the fly which could then be efficiently re-used by the rendering routine? After all, the whole point of Von Neumann architecture after all is that a computer can modify its own code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you perfectly sure you are not a victim of the inner platform effect? Most people that can program stack machines would also be able to write the same expression in C. Couldn't your core routine just accept a function pointer? The compiler can do the rest.

Comment: The eventual goal is to use this DLL in a Visual Basic application with a nice user interface. Users will enter the formula in using standard mathematical syntax, then it will be translated into something usable by my DLL. Currently this is RPN, but that seems too slow. In any case, RPN is a good way to organize formulas, so it will likely be an intermediate stage either way. I know it's inefficient, that is why I'm trying to bring the code execution back to the machine level. But if you call this being the victim of the inner platform effect, then what are languages like Python and Lisp?

Comment: If you expect end users to enter formulas, fair enough. As a second point, the problem of the inner platform effect is not distance from the machine, but the attempt to build a machine similar to your compiler within your programming language. In other terms, the attempt to make a hammer with a hammer. Python and Lisp are far from the machine, but they are distinctly different from other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of self-modifying code in C. Any attempt to pass control to a data block that is in the "data" memory, say, by casting a data pointer to a function pointer, is undefined behavior. This model is there to let you program in C for non vov-neuman computers.

This said, you can probably optimize your RPN code to run much faster by replacing sequences of if-then-else statements with function pointers or a switch statement. You could also program the target function into a dynamic library, read it at runtime, and use it in rendering.

Comment: All right, I have 3 further questions.
1. Even though it is "undefined behavior" so that C can run on other kinds of processors, my application is only ever going to be used on an x86 or x68 machine running Windows. Maybe it's not the "right" thing to do, but I could still do it, right?

2. Why is a switch statement faster?

3. Do you mean to suggest that I should write a function to turn my operations in to C code, then pass that code to a compiler and generate a DLL on the fly, then import the function from that DLL?

Comment: @BigEndian 1. On most platforms you can beat the protection, and run the binary code that you generate dynamically. Beating the protection may be a hard task, though. 2. Switch statement is faster than `if` because it is a calculated jump. Compiler puts offsets of your cases into an array, and jumps to an address pointed to by the index that corresponds to the `case` constant. 3. There may be multiple ways to produce that DLL, from the user writing it from scratch to your specification, to you writing a utility that reads a txt file and calls C compiler to make DLL, to what you suggested in 3.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start with the switch. If it's still too slow I'll delve into one of the more difficult solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If using C++ is an option, I would suggest you try using LLVM - use their IRBuilder to convert the function into LLVM IR, run optimization passes, then use the LLVM JIT to compile the function at runtime

http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that for future use.